# How did Inquisitors know about Vin's parentage?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

Since they found out that Vin was a mistborn, they must have known at least one of her parents was an allomancer.

However, in the throne hall when the Lord Ruler and Inquisitors faced Vin at least some of them (at least Kar) seemed to know that her father was the Lord Prelan. But how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all likelihood, they knew from the start. The Steel Inquisition hated having a non-Inquisitor looking over them, so they probably kept an eye on him (not difficult, considering that they were Tineyes). Vin's mother disguises herself as a poor noble, and at some point that disguise broke down, at which point the Inquisition followed her tracks.

That was when they found and caught Reen, who died swearing that Vin already died, somewhat plausible given how Vin got her earring in the first place.

Comment: Even if that's the case, why didn't they punish Lord Prelan before?

Comment: Reen is Vin's half-brother through a different father. https://coppermind.net/wiki/Reen They needed a child for undeniable proof, otherwise the Lord Prelan just denies everything and hides behind his office.

Comment: kar states that the steel inquisition purposely spent decades (in not centuries) corrupting the obligators. they kept careful track of all of the obligators and what skaa women they were sleeping with, specifically, for exactly this scenario, where the obligator does not kill the child/mother skaa. Now of course they needed the child in question to prove to the lord ruler that the head obligator was corrupt. Kar himself was not quite sure, but having found the mother, and having the brother tell him there was a second child, but she was dead. Then finding vin herself, a mistborn, meaning she..

Comment: came from a very pureblood line, aka someone like the lord prelan's line, who has a missing skaa daughter, of the right age as vin. connect the dots, and use the lord rulers ability to detect lies and boom, checkmate.